# Unknown function in PHP Netbeans - how to suppress?

Tags: php, netbeans

Since I develop on `localhost` but deploy elsewhere, and since I don't want to have to force my sites to be under a Windows partition's root directory (currently F:\web_dev\htdocs), code like this:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/projXY/database/database_common.php');
OdbcExec($sql); // defined in the file above
```

causes Netbeans to issue a "Warning: unknown function".

Now, I could get round this by using a directory structure like :

```
F:\project_1  
F:\project_2
```

instead of

```
F:\web_dev_htdocs\project_1  
F:\web_dev_htdocs\project_2
```

and then using

```
require_once('/database/database_common.php');
```

***BUT*** that imposes constraints on where the end-user an install my site.

Simplest by far would be to tell NetBeans which local directory corresponds to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, but I can't find a configuration option for that. I am sure this is a common problem. Any suggestions?

---

Update: NetbBeans v7.0.1

Comment: You should at least try to fix your typos :)

Comment: What version of Netbeans are you using?

Comment: +1 for both (although I am willing to bet that me typos were transpositions - I am cursed by them. Sorry) I will upadate the question for NB version. Thanks, both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the `/path/to/projXY/database/` directory to your project's include path. Netbeans will then pick up the files there and use them as code references.

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html#phpIncludePath

### Addendum

Relying on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is generally a bad idea. For one, it eliminates the ability to run parts of your application via the console / command line.

You should instead either use configurable, absolute paths to shared libraries or do as in [Brandon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072920/unknown-function-in-php-netbeans-how-to-suppress/7073101#7073101) and use a relative path from `__DIR__` (PHP 5.3) or `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: These are two separate points. Your NetBEans option solution works for the question that I asked. I will now ask another question about how best to handle include paths. Thanks, both

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for or not, but I commonly use:

```
 require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'file.php');
```

Comment: If I have a multi-level hierarchy and some common functionality (dataebase, error handling, etc) which can be called from any level - how do I handlt that? E.g, my error handling requires a CSS frile from $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']\css\my.cc