# Problems with include paths

Tags: php

My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072920/unknown-function-in-php-netbeans-how-to-suppress) broght up some discussion which suggested that I am wrong to use the likes of

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/proj/database/database-common.php');
```

and should, instead be using

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/database/database-common.php');
```

BUT, I have a multi-level hierarchy and some common functionality (dataebase, error handling, etc) which can be called from any level - how do I handlt that? E.g, my error handling requires a CSS file from $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']\css\my.css

If I do not have `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as an anchor point, can I use something else? If not, how do I handle that a common file may wish to include another, but does not know from which level it itself is being included?

E.g.:

```
root
     `- databse
      `- validation
```

If validation/common.php wants to include database/database_common.php thhen, without an anchor, validation/common.php cannot know the path to database_common.php It is *not* `..\database/database_common.php` if validation/common.php was incldued from a file in the root directory (and this is a simplified example)

My philiosophy is to always require a file in the file which uses it, so I can't just include everthing in the root directory files ....

Can someoen clarify best pracise on this for me?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a bootstrap file which is used across all others file and define all global parameters there, something like

```
# bootstrap.php
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

and the require this master file in every file which needs to include other files so your following requires will become

```
require 'path/to/bootstrap.php';
require APPLICATION_PATH . '/database/common.php';
```

This will solve in part your problem, but keeps thing consistent, the only part which change is the first require, but you can use relative paths to keeps code portable.

I'd not use `include_path` changes because it will slow path resolution because php will search through all directories in the include path and `stat` is one of the most expensive syscall. Example: if you you have this include path 
`.:/dir1:/dir2:/dir3` and you require a file named `foo.php` which is in `dir3` php will make the following four stat calls:

```
./foo.php
/dir1/foo.php
/dir2/foo.php
/dir3/foo.php
```

For this reason you should always use absolute paths when requiring files and should keep the include path limited to one or two paths.

Alternatively, if you're using OOP you can always use [autoloading for your classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) which remove the need for requiring files and works pretty well. A good example of this technique is given in [Zend Framework autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.load.html)

Comment: @Mawg I don't know if everyone uses this approach. I left self made code (that often leads to spaghetti code) three years ago and moved to zend framework and RoR because of code reuse and mostly convention over configuration. One of my primary goal is to avoid this kind of problems. I learnt a lot of good practices which are pretty standard a could be reused across different projects and shared with other colleagues by speaking a common language.

Answer (score 0):

Set your include_path in your php.ini.  This will be searched for the include.  Define your directory structure well so that the included files get overrided.

In your php.ini set the following:

```
include_path=".:/dir/first:/dir/second"
```

This means that include and require files are searched for in . (the current directory, then /dir/first and finally /dir/second

So require_once 'database/common.php' could be found in:

```
/dir/first/database/common.php
/dir/second/database/common.php
```

Comment: that might work if I exhautively list every subdirectory (until I add another), but doesn't seem to adress my question - a PHP include file doesn't know from where it was included, so how can it make a relative path which is valid when included from several different levels of a site?